# openjdk breaking docker build

Tags: java, docker, java-8, debian

When I type `docker build -t nameOfImageToBeBuilt .` in the root directory of the code from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/Dwolla/atlassian-crowd-docker), I get the following error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  openjdk8-8.171.11-r0:
    breaks: world[openjdk8=8.151.12-r0]
```

What specifically do I need to change in the code from [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/Dwolla/atlassian-crowd-docker) in order for this error not to be thrown?

Comment: this isn't really docker-specific. you should break down your problem into steps, see where it fails (in this case something in alpine updates). drill down, divide and conquer.

Comment: @the8472 This user is new to docker.  All the code is available in the GitHub repository in the link.  This is reproducible on any computer in only a few minutes.  Elaboration of the specific steps required to solve this problem would be a good answer that would get marked accepted and +1.

Comment: I'm trying to help you with problem-solving, not solve the problem ;) That's why it's just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying version 8-8.171.11-r0 breaks (not sure what this means) version 8.151.12-r0, which is what you're trying to install.

I fixed this by specifying 8-8.171.11-r0 in my Dockerfile.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you please show your exact syntax.  I am getting a different error when I just put in `docker build -t nameOfImageToBeBuilt .`

Comment: The error I am getting is `ERROR: 'openjdk8=8-8.171.11-r0' is not a valid dependency, format is name(@tag)([<>~=]version)`

Comment: And then another attempt gave `ERROR: 'openjdk8=openjdk8-8.171.11-r0' is not a valid dependency, format is name(@tag)([<>~=]version)`